# Sum of matrix elements stay the same after inversion

Tags: matrices

I found something interesting but I'm not sure how to proof it.

Suppose we have a square Matrix $M$ which is invertible and each column sums up to $1$ with only positive elements. Then the sum of all elements of the inversion $M^{-1}$ will be the same as the sum of all elements in $M$.

Can someone help me why this holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that each column sums to 1 tells us that if $v$ is the vector with all 1s as its entries, then $M^Tv=v$. This tells us that we also have $(M^{T})^{-1}v=v$, and since $(M^T)^{-1}=(M^{-1})^T$, we know that all the columns of $M^{-1}$ also sum to 1. In any matrix where each column sums to 1, the total sum of the entries in $M$ is $n$.  Thus the two will have the same sum.

Comment: First, thanks for your great input! How can I conclude from $M^Tv=v$ that $(M^T)^{-1}v=v$ holds?

Comment: Multiply both sides of the first equation by $(M^T)^{-1}$ and use the fact that a matrix times its inverse is the identity.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer.